# Automatic Authentication of Client Device

Tags: c#, node.js, security, one-time-password

All,

I have a web app where users can interact with data that has been sent from a device. This is a custom device which is only intended to be used with code which we provide with the device.

On the device, we would like the ability to authenticate with the server before we send data.

In a naive implementation, I could just store an ID for the device and send it to the server with every request. However, that would be insecure since anyone with the ID could send data to the server.

Here are a few ideas I had.

1. Store a "username" and "password" on the device. Every time the device logs in, the server sends a new password for the device to use during the next authentication. This doesn't feel quite right. Seems fragile and insecure.
2. Generate a OTP and send it to the server with each request. This feels like it will work, but I'm not sure how to generate an OTP. Would this work if many requests were sent over a short period of time?

A few questions.

1. Is there an industry best practice for this scenario?
2. Does TOTP work for multiple-requests in a short-period of time?

The device runs C#. The server runs Node.JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TOTP will not work as expected if many requests were sent over a short period of time, the requests might wrongly invalidated because of race conditions.

Since you have native control on the device, you should consider leveraging Public Key infrastructure(PKI). A simple workflow can be as follows:

- Generate public-private certificate pair or procure one from certificate authority
- Install private certificate in the device's certificate store and public certificate on your server's trust store
- Sign the request payload with the private certificate and validate the same at server using public certificate.

All standard guidelines of PKI can be applied.